# How do subtypes drive domain options?

Tags: esri-geodatabase, domains, subtype

I understand the use of domains and even that of subtypes, but in using them together is where I feel as though I am getting lost. I have taken the online course provided by ESRI to try and understand a bit more and I understand there too, but still lack some further understanding.

Software: ArcMap 10.7.1

So, my thought is as follows:

```
Domain Attribute: pipe_type
Coded Value: 1: Water, 2: Sewer

Subtypes: pipe_material
Coded Value: 1: Ductile Iron Pipe, 2: Concrete, 3: Polyethylene, 4: P0lyvinyl Chloride, 5: Copper, 6: Steel
```

Not all of these can run water or sewer, but some cross over and allow both. I would like to restrict the subtypes to that in which is selected either Water or Sewer.

In typing this I feel as though the subtype should be pipe_type and the materials should be the domain, but then again, how do I limit based on which is selected?

Comment: Attribute domains are rules that describe the legal values of a field type, providing a method for enforcing data integrity. Attribute domains are used to constrain the values allowed in any particular attribute for a table or feature class. If the features in a feature class or nonspatial objects in a table have been **grouped into subtypes.** https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/an-overview-of-attribute-domains.htm

Comment: Like the OP, I understand domains (on their own), and I understand subtypes (on their own).  But I'm totally confused when domains and subtypes are combined.  ESRI does not do a good job of explaining how the two interact.